# apply jquery plugin to dynamic html content

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic

If I have a div in a class that is dynamically created

I need to apply a plugin to the dynamically created div above by class name "mdsl"

I need to in document.ready do :-

```
$('.mdsl').slick({
    dots: false,
    arrows: true,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 4,
    responsive: [  // etc etc
});
```

But as the mdsl class div is dynamic, what is the JQuery to replace

```
$('.mdsl').slick({
    // ...
});
```

Comment: It seems you'll need to initialize the plugin after the element exists in the DOM. How are you loading the dynamic content?

Comment: There isn't any magic way to replace it. You have to call it when it does exist...such as in an ajax callback